# The “what” determines the “how”, although in the long run the “how” determines the “what”

Tags: ethics

I recently stumbled upon a quote from Heinrich Neuhaus' book 'Art of Piano Playing' that got me thinking:

> 'The "what" determines the "how", although in the long run the "how" determines the "what".'

While it was originally meant for another context, I'm curious about its implications in ethical situations. What do you think this statement means ethically? Is there validity to it?

Comment: If you want to create a sculpture you select the appropriate tools to use : the how.  But eventually the skilled use of the tools (technique) governs the complexity of the artwork that can be produced.

Comment: Would have to see it in context to know what the author means. "What" "how" "who" "when" "where" all can influence each other in the long run or the short run.

Comment: That's poetic and all, but I don't really know what it has to do with philosophy. You'd probably need to expand on what *you think* it means, and how it relates to ethics, and then we can maybe tell you there's validity to that.

Comment: Could "what" and "how" refer to "ends" and "means" respectively. So in a ethical context it might mean that the ends may justify the means in the short term and one can get away with small temporary maneuvers but in the long term the means catches up with the individual and plays a deciding factor in determining the results.